# Run diff command to compare all files in directory

Tags: batch, diff

I have two folders having in theory an identical folder structure and the same files.

I wish to check for differences between the two copies in the two folders. I can run `diff folder1/file1 folder2/file1` one by one but this is time consuming.

Is there a way to identify which are the files which differ in the two folders? If not is there at least a way to compare the contents of a folder with the contents of the second folder?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've missed the `-r` (recursive) option to `diff`:

```
diff -r folder1 folder2
```

For a concise output also add the `-q` flag; it will only output that the files differ, but doesn't output the actual differences. See the manpage (`man 1 diff`) for more information and options.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a lot of files and subfolders, you'll probably want to use meld (apt-get install meld), which is a visual diff and merge tool.

Comment: Meld is one example of a GUI diff tool (good one). There's also Kompare, QDiff, etc.

Comment: is good tool indeed